# Argparse subparser help displayed before options

Tags: python, argparse

With argparse, currently my `main.py --help` looks like this

```
usage: main.py [--options] <command>

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --debug     Logs extra information for debugging
  --version   show program's version number and exit
  --license   reads the GPLv3

commands:

    install   install packages
    remove    remove packages
    update    update package list and upgrade the system
```

is there an easy way to make the subparser commands display before the global options?

my configuration is a bit long to post at the moment but I can if context is needed. I don't have anything crazy going on, this is the important stuff.

```
formatter = lambda prog: argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter(prog,
                                                max_help_position=64)
bin_name = Path(argv[0]).name
version = __version__
parser = nalaParser(    formatter_class=formatter,
                        usage=f'{bin_name} [--options] <command>', 
                        )

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='commands', metavar='', dest='command')
parser._optionals.title = "options"

install_parser = subparsers.add_parser('install', help='install packages')
remove_parser = subparsers.add_parser('remove', help='remove packages')
update_parser = subparsers.add_parser('update', help='update package list and upgrade the system')

parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true', help='Logs extra information for debugging')
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version=f'{bin_name} {version}')
parser.add_argument('--license', action=GPLv3)
```

Since I was already subclassing I just added this method below to nalaParser

```
def format_help(self):
    formatter = self._get_formatter()

    # usage
    formatter.add_usage(self.usage, self._actions,
                        self._mutually_exclusive_groups)

    # description
    formatter.add_text(self.description)

    index = -1
    # Put options last in the group
    for action_group in self._action_groups[:]:
        index = + 1
        if action_group.title == 'options':
            self._action_groups.append(self._action_groups.pop(index))

    # positionals, optionals and user-defined groups
    for action_group in self._action_groups:
        formatter.start_section(action_group.title)
        formatter.add_text(action_group.description)
        formatter.add_arguments(action_group._group_actions)
        formatter.end_section()


    # epilog
    formatter.add_text(self.epilog)

    # determine help from format above
    return formatter.format_help()
```

Comment: look at the code of the  `format_help` method.  That's what sets up the formatter, including the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parser.format_help` passes the `action_groups` to the formatter in the order that they were created.

```
In [24]: parser._action_groups
Out[24]: 
[<argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0x7f8167ac02e0>,
 <argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0x7f8167ac0850>,
 <argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0x7f8167ac0490>]
In [25]: [a.title for a in parser._action_groups]
Out[25]: ['positional arguments', 'options', 'commands']
```

The default groups are `positional` and `options`.  `add_subparsers` puts its  Action in the `positional` group, except when given a `title`.  In that case it makes a new group.

You could tweak the `format_help` to reorder the groups that it passes to the formatter.

Or it might work to change the 'positional arguments' title as you did with the optionals (instead of giving `subparsers` the `title` parameter).

Anyways, the key to the behavior is in these two methods.

Comment: I've been looking at this stuff too long. I swear I looked format_help up and down when you commented earlier but couldn't figure it out. Thanks for nudging me I got it figured out. i overrode the method and Before argparse iterates self._action_groups I iterate it, find the one with title options and move it to the end basically.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `format_help` method of `argparse.ArgumentParser` and rearrange the order of the action groups before calling `super()`.

```py
class MyParser(ArgumentParser):

    def format_help(self):

        # Put options last in the group
        opitions_action_group = [a for a in self._action_groups if a.title == 'options']
        self._action_groups = [a for a in self._action_groups if a.title != 'options']
        if opitions_action_group:
            self._action_groups.append(opitions_action_group[0])

        return super().format_help()


# Parent parser (so 'help' is available for all sub-parsers).
parent_parser = MyParser()

# Main parser.
desc = ('Take some action as described below.')
main_parser = MyParser(description=desc, add_help=False, formatter_class=HelpFormatter, parents=[parent_parser])

# Sub-parsers.
subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title='action')
subparsers.add_parser('action1', add_help=False, parents=[parent_parser], description='Description of action1.')
subparsers.add_parser('action2', add_help=False, parents=[parent_parser], description='Description of action2.')
subparsers.add_parser('action3', add_help=False, parents=[parent_parser], description='Description of action3.')

main_parser.parse_args()
```

Parsing the above with `-h` results in the following...

```bash
usage: cs-aws [-h] {action1,action2,action3} ...

Take some action as described below.

action:
  {action1,action2,action3}

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```